# Dojo Mobile: Bug in tabbar? Broken image when scrolling

Tags: javascript, mobile, tabbar, dojo

I'm trying to build a Dojo Mobile App at the moment and got a little problem on iOS which I couldn't figure out how to solve. I need a tabbar at the bottom of the application. I positioned it and everything works fine until I start to scroll the content above. The same also happens with demo application from the tutorials (TweetView). Does anybody has any idea how to solve this? Is there a workaround? Can maybe somebody tell me, whether it will be fixed in 1.7? At the moment I'm using 1.6 and it works fine on Android and also on my desktop webkit browser. The error only occurs on iOS. Here some screenshots:

Before scrolling:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoOqT.png)

After scrolling:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0XAs.png)

If anybody has any advice I would be thankful.

Thanks,
Ralf

Comment: Your "after scrolling" image for some reason constantly "504 gateway timeout" on me.

Comment: Just the "after scrolling"? That's strange. Anyway, here is another [>>link<<](http://s7.directupload.net/images/110802/2o8tdo36.png) Hope this works :-)

Comment: This is quite strange.  Haven't seen anything like it.  Did you mess with the CSS files?  Are you using bitmap masks?

Comment: No I haven't mess with the CSS. Just used a .png strip and worked with iconPos1 and iconPos2. Anyway, the screenshots I have posted are from the application provided on the dojo website. Here some links: [Dojo Mobile Tuts](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/) and [TweetView Demo App](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/mobile/tweetview/settings/demo/) Maybe somebody can post a solution with a tabbar at the bottom that worked for him on iOS. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for the Problem was not to use iconPos1 and iconPos2 and iconBase but instead just icon1 and icon2 in the TabBarButton tag. iconPos and iconBase really seams to have a bug but unfortunately I couldn't get a confirmation of that from the dojo developers.